# pandas: Is there a way to specify a title for a simple OLS regression output

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I am wondering if there is way to specify a title for a simple OLS regression output. I have the following regression output, and I am going to be doing quite a few of them. I would like that it look something like the following:

```
MODEL 1: OLS Regression Results ## This is a preferred title

Dep. Variable:  billsum_support     R-squared:  0.019
Model:  OLS     Adj. R-squared:     0.017
Method:     Least Squares   F-statistic:    15.63
Date:   Mon, 09 May 2016    Prob (F-statistic):     5.15e-23
Time:   04:32:43    Log-Likelihood:     -6110.2
No. Observations:   6597    AIC:    1.224e+04
Df Residuals:   6588    BIC:    1.230e+04
Df Model:   8       
Covariance Type:    nonrobust       
    coef    std err     t   P>|t|   [95.0% Conf. Int.]
const   0.9745  0.032   30.570  0.000   0.912 1.037
years_exp   3.882e-05   0.001   0.057   0.955   -0.001 0.001
leg_totalbills  0.0017  0.001   2.538   0.011   0.000 0.003
log_diff_rgdp   0.4085  0.222   1.838   0.066   -0.027 0.844
unemployment    -0.0099     0.004   -2.785  0.005   -0.017 -0.003
expendituresfor     6.519e-06   8.07e-07    8.082   0.000   4.94e-06 8.1e-06
direct_expenditures     1.334e-05   1.56e-06    8.533   0.000   1.03e-05 1.64e-05
indirect_expenditures   -6.823e-06  9.27e-07    -7.358  0.000   -8.64e-06 -5e-06
Republican  0.0806  0.017   4.839   0.000   0.048 0.113
sen     0.0441  0.024   1.847   0.065   -0.003 0.091
Omnibus:    2344.287    Durbin-Watson:  1.717
Prob(Omnibus):  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):   17321.494
Skew:   1.507   Prob(JB):   0.00
Kurtosis:   10.344  Cond. No.   1.55e+15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print('MODEL 1: OLS Regression Results') this of course is Python 3 you can look up the print command to see how to substitute a variable for any part of the string... So if you are looping through something you can use the loop counter to modify the string..

Comment: Super! I like the format much better as well! Thank you.